# How can I build my SSIS and SSRS projects in team city?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, teamcity, ssis

Runner Type: Visual Studio(sln)
Visual Studio : Visual Studio 2008
Targets: Rebuild
Configuration: Development
Platform: default

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOR SSIS there is a warning like this:

The project file "SB.SSIS.Package\SB.SSIS.Package.dtproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built.

FOR SSRS here is the warning:

The project file "SB.Report\SB.Report.rptproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
When I run the project. It was successful but there are no files that should be in the bin.

In SSRS, I dont think I still need this to build cause the .ds and .rdl files are still the same and only trasfered in the bin. Am I correct?

But for SSIS, I think It should build.
Do I forgot some steps?

Comment: How have you defined your build?

Comment: I my SSIS build this is how I defined it:

Runner Type: Visual Studio(sln)
Visual Studio : Visual Studio 2008
Targets: Rebuild
Configuration: Development
Platform: default

This is a Visual Studio 2008 .dtproj file

Comment: This is only one step whose purpose is to just build the project. But unfortunately it says that MSBUILD do not support the .dtproj file.

Comment: Building an SSRS project does not just copy the files to the output. It also, if needed, downgrades them to the target SQL version. (The source files are configured for the version of SQL that matches SSDT). You're supposed to deploy the build output, not the source.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, MSBuild doesn't support building of SSIS, SSRS and SSAS projects out of the box.

You have at least two options to build SSIS, SSRS, SSAS projects on TeamCity:

1. **write custom MSBuild script**:

   - find proper MSBuild task that can build these project types (for instance, you can discover http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/) or write your own task
   - write custom MSBuild script that uses task and put it to source control
   - add **MSBuild build step** to build configuration in TeamCity
2. **use devenv.com**:

   - install **SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio** to build agent (BI studio can build them, but ordinary Visual Studio can't)
   - add **Command-line build step**

     - Command executable: %VS2008_Path%\devenv.com
     - Command parameters: MySolution.sln /rebuild Release
   - Artifacts path, for instance:

     - SSAS: MyProject\bin\*.asdatabase
     - SSIS: MyProject\bin\*.dtsx
     - SSRS: MyProject\bin\*.rdl

%VSxxxx_Path% - agent parameter that TeamCity automatically creates when detects Visual Studio installation on build agents (for instance, %VS2008_Path% or %VS2010_Path%).

P.S. I think, you're right, that you don't need to build SSRS projects.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. 1 additional point I would add is that for the command-line build step in TeamCity, the "Run" property should be set to "Executable with parameters" and not "Custom script" to be able to set the command executable and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> In SSRS, I dont think I still need this to build cause the .ds and
>   .rdl files are still the same and only trasfered in the bin. Am I
>   correct?

No, you are not. 
In recent versions of Visual studio rdl files would work only with SQL server 2016 and fail with other versions. you need to build project and use rdl files from bin\Debug to use them with SSRS services older than that